# Executing function for each packed parameter in variadic template

Tags: c++, lambda, variadic-templates

I noticed the following line in the open-source project [FeatherKit](https://github.com/therocode/featherkit):

```
int _[] = { (SubscribeToType<MessageTypes>( bus, receiver, desubscribers, unsubscribe ), 0)... };
```

With the following context:

```
template<class... MessageTypes>
void Subscribe( MessageBus& bus, MessageReceiver<MessageTypes...>& receiver, bool unsubscribe ) {
    std::vector<std::function<void()>> desubscribers;
    int _[] = { (SubscribeToType<MessageTypes>( bus, receiver, desubscribers, unsubscribe ), 0)... };
    (void) _;
    receiver.desubscribers = desubscribers;
}
```

It's obviously executing the function SubscribeToType for each parameter in the variadic template.

My question is twofold:

1. How, exactly, does the line work? How come parameter unpacking is allowing that function to execute for each parameter in the variadic template?
2. I am very certain this line could be replaced by a lambda. How could you replace the line with a lambda expression?

I've contacted the original author of FeatherKit, but he wasn't able to answer my question at that time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. How, exactly, does the line work? How come parameter unpacking is allowing that function to execute for each parameter in the variadic template?

A parameter pack expansion is some pattern involving a parameter pack followed by `...`

So `expr(T)...` is a pack expansion with `expr(T)` as its pattern, and it expands to `expr(T0), expr(T1), expr(T2), ..., expr(TN)` for each `Ti` in the parameter pack.

A pack expansion can only be used in certain contexts, such as argument lists, or initializer lists, so in this case the results of each sub-expression is being used to form an initializer list for the array `int _[]`. The array is unused and only exists so that its initializer can be used as the context in which to do the pack expansion.  Each sub-expression is of the form `(SubscribeToType<Ti>(blah, blah), 0)` which means the result of the function call is discarded and the expression has the value 0. This is a bit of a kluge to allow the pack expansion to produce a braced-init-list containing N integers, because that's what's needed to initialize the array.

> 2. I am very certain this line could be replaced by a lambda. How could you replace the line with a lambda expression?

Why would you want to?

It could, but you'd need a very similar pack expansion in the lambda, so it wouldn't simplify anything.

Comment: To address point #2, I felt that using the initializer of an int array was 'hack'ish and not very clean. I thought that a lambda iterating over the param pack would be very clean and clear to the reader.

Comment: How would you "iterate" over the pack? Bear in mind it's a pack of types, you don't have an argument pack that you could actually pass to a lambda. The array is hackish, but just saying "use a lambda" doesn't offer a neater solution (or any solution at all ;-)

Comment: You're right, I just had the feeling that there must've been a cleaner solution that I didn't know to execute a function call for each param in the pack. I know now :)